# HTML Not Displaying Correctly In Bootstrap Modal After Being Dynamically Generated With JQuery

Tags: jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal

Im currently using jQuery and Bootstrap to display data in a modal. I am able to get the data to appear on the page but the H3 and P tags in the append are ignored. Here is the code that I am working with:

```
var modalContent = $("#modalContent_Category_" + catID + "_Task_" + taskID);    
modalContent[0].append("<h3>Today's Entries</h3>" +
                "<p>Entry Number: " + JSON.stringify(performed.id) + "</p>" +            
                "<p>Description: " + JSON.stringify(performed.description) + "</p>" +
                "<p>Time Completed: " + JSON.stringify(performed.submittedDateTime) + "</p>" +
                "<p>Completed By: " + JSON.stringify(performed.name) + "</p>"             
);
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the solution. All thats needed is to change the line modelContent[0].append(...) to $(modelContent[0]).append(...) .